# Memory of imageviews from on activity to another

Tags: android

If I go from one activity to another (so activity is put onPause), what happens all the memory used by the image views of the previous activity? does it get recycled? IF not , what should be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing-  onPause doesn't do anything except put the activity int he background.  The memory remains and is used.  If you wanted to you could manually recycle bitmaps, but that's more appropriate for onStop (when you're completely not on screen) than onPause.  And you'd need to be able to reverse things in onStart.